# ')' or operator expected on LinqDataSource where clause

Tags: asp.net, where-clause, linqdatasource

`Where="((ProgModelID == @ProgModelID) || (@ProgModelID == @ShowAll)) && (((FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName) LIKE '%' + @Name + '%') || ((FirstName + ' ' + LastName) LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'))"`

I need to concatenate the full name together when comparing against a `TextBox` in order to filter a `GridView`, but this error comes up when I try to run it. The error changes to `Expression expected` when I place `[]` around each `FirstName`, `MiddleName` and `LastName`.

### Update

I have a textbox which a user can type a name into to filter a `GridView`'s results. the `GridView` has a `LinqDataSource`. The problem is the name is divided in the database into 3 parts: first, middle, last. I want to be able to filter by first+last name, as well as first+middle+last name. The areas related to ProgModel are for a `DropDownList` and already function if the sections related to `@Name` are removed.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to avoid this error, and a probable cause for it. I added computed columns to the view the LinqDataSource was pulling rows from for FullName (first, middle, last) and Name (first, last).

I then changed `LIKE` to `.Contains()` and received a `no applicable method 'contains' exists in type 'string'` error. What happened was I forgot to add `ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"` to the `ControlParameter` for the TextBox (I found out this solution from the link [here](http://naspinski.net/post/No-applicable-method-Contains-exists-in-type-String.aspx)). That managed to fix everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need just one more `)` at the end is all..This will complete the wrap after your `&&`

Try this:

```
Where="((ProgModelID == @ProgModelID) || (@ProgModelID == @ShowAll)) && 
(((FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName) LIKE '%' + @Name + '%') 
|| ((FirstName + ' ' + LastName) LIKE '%' + @Name + '%')))"
```

Or - to make it a little easier to read and still get the same result, remove one of the `(` before `FirstName + ' '` - like:

```
Where="((ProgModelID == @ProgModelID) || (@ProgModelID == @ShowAll)) && 
((FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName) LIKE '%' + @Name + '%') 
|| ((FirstName + ' ' + LastName) LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'))"
```

Ultimately the error message says it all :)

Comment: I still receive the same error. But thanks for noticing the extra parenthesis. Am I not allowed to concatenate strings **before** a `LIKE`?

Comment: It's looking super complex - the way you're trying to achieve your goal - perhaps update your question with what you're actually trying to do, might be some much better ways to handle it..